# Using command prompt to delete specific files within downloads folder

Tags: c#, cmd

I'm trying to use the following code to delete specific files from my downloads folder -

```
var process = new Process();
            var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal,
                FileName = "cmd.exe",
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                UseShellExecute = false
            };

            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            process.Start();

            process.StandardInput.WriteLine("cd C://users/%username%/downloads");
            process.StandardInput.WriteLine("del /f Secci*");
```

When debugging the code - the command prompt window flashes open but then instantly closes (even though it didn't specify for it to be hidden in the code) so I'm struggling to see if it's even managing to CD into the correct directory. Currently the file(s) are not being deleted from the downloads folder either. This is part of a 'Before Test' class within our test automation project. Would be great if someone could give some suggestions on why this might not be working?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you're writing commands to the console to perform deletion rather than using .NET BCLs in the `System.IO` namespace?

Comment: If you really want to do what you seem to be trying to do, then pass the CMD exe a command line that uses the `/k` option (or `/c`), and pass the two commands with a `&` separator between them.  But, as @rory.ap says, you should probably just use `System.IO` calls to do what you'd like

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. No specific reason - I'm trying to delete more than one file and had problems using other methods as they only accepted one wildcard etc or pattern. So I thought the most effective and quickest implementation would be to use console commands. Would you happen to have a reference to the .NET BCLs so I could take a look please?

Comment: You can Google it.  And console commands are a sub-optimal alternative to anything available in the managed (.NET) context in pretty much every way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For deleting in cmd prompt. Try this

```
string file = "Secci*";          
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.Start();
process.StandardInput.WriteLine("cd C://users/%username%/downloads");          
process.StandardInput.WriteLine(string.Format("del \"{0}\"", file));
```

If you are trying to use System.IO, Try this.

```
using System.IO;

string file = "Secci*";  
//Because "SpecialFolder" doesn't have Downloads in it, this is my workaround. There may be better ones out there.
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
path = path.Replace("Documents", "Downloads"); 
string[] List = Directory.GetFiles(path, file);
foreach (string f in List)
{
   File.Delete(f);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help :) both of them worked great.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the files by enumerating the directory.
Once you have the files that match your criteria, you can iterate over them and perform actions on them.

```
var dir = new DirectoryInfo("C://users/%username%/downloads");

foreach (var file in dir.EnumerateFiles("Secci*")) {
    file.Delete();
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles?view=netframework-4.7.2